# Unity: Conflict between new InputSystem and old EventSystem

Tags: unity-game-engine

When using the new InputSystem. If I add a Canvas component to my Scene it brings automatically the old EventSystem and I see this error in my console:

```
InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling to Input System package in Player Settings.
UnityEngine.Input.get_mousePosition () (at <213e6bf8f2dd495fbd693e6ce506136b>:0)
UnityEngine.UI.MultipleDisplayUtilities.GetMousePositionRelativeToMainDisplayResolution () (at /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/MultipleDisplayUtilities.cs:40)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseInput.get_mousePosition () (at /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/BaseInput.cs:75)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.UpdateModule () (at /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/StandaloneInputModule.cs:175)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.TickModules () (at /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:328)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () (at /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:343)
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Looks like the solution was in an automatic update button in the Inspector:

[image]

Comment: "Is this answer outdated?" -> unfortunately, I had to answer "**`No`**"

Comment: This is the missing piece in [migration documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Migration.html). Thank you!

Comment: It's still works, but requires install the package `com.unity.inputsystem`.

Comment: this did not work for me. problem persisted.

Answer (score 60):

You probably tried to import a new input system package for multiple input devices compatibility. These type of errors are due to conflict between old and new input system packages and are probably resolved in latest updates.
To resolve this issue, Go to **Edit** -> **Project Settings**->**Player**->Under **Other Settings** under **Configuration** is the option **Active Input Handling**. Select **Both**. Unity will restart. Now your problem should be solved. You will be able to use old input system packages and the new ones also simultaneously.
Cheers.
P.S

[Click on this image link to view where these settings are in Unity editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72mG.png)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Player** > **Configuration** > **Active Input Handling** > **Both**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

go to edit -> Player -> Other settings ->  Configuration last option -> You can select the input system and then unity will restart then it should not throw an error :)